# where to load SELECT MAX(id) in vbnet

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having a problem getting the value of the last `id` from a table.

Since loading the whole column will give me a problem in the future (`DataTable` has its limit) so I decided to look for another solution, but I don't have luck to make it work.

I have the string command but I don't know where to store the returned value.
Here is my code:

```
        Dim query As String = "SELECT MAX(id) AS LastId FROM Table1"
    Dim dtmain As New DataTable
    Try
        With sqlcmd
            .CommandText = query
            .Connection = sqlcon
        End With

        With sqladp
            .SelectCommand = sqlcmd
            .Fill(dtMain)
        End With
        MsgBox("last id = " & dtmain.Rows(0)("LastId"))
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

I get nothing and the `msgbox` won't even show.

*note: I want the last `id` from the table and **NOT** the inserted `id`.*

This are my references and declarations:

```
   Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Private conn As OleDbConnection
    Private adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Private cmdd As OleDbCommand
```

also i added `Microsoft ADO Ext 2.8 for DDL and Security` at my project reference

Answer (score 1):

If source of your data is in your current database:

```
Dim dbConnect As Database
Dim rstRecordset As DAO.Recordset

Set dbConnect = Access.CurrentDb

Dim query As String = "SELECT MAX(id) AS LastId FROM Table1"

Set rstRecordset = dbConnect .OpenRecordset(query)
MsgBox("last id = " & rstRecordset.Fields(0).value & ""))

dbConnect.Close
Set dbConnect = Nothing
Set rstRecordset = Nothing
```

If source of your data is in another Access database:

```
Dim cnnConn As ADODB.connection
Dim rstRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmdCommand As ADODB.Command

' Open the connection.
Set cnnConn = New ADODB.connection
With cnnConn
    .ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
     .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "pass"
     .Open "D:\Databases\Database.mdb"
End With

' Set the command text.
Set cmdCommand = New ADODB.Command
Set cmdCommand.ActiveConnection = cnnConn
With cmdCommand
    .CommandText = "SELECT MAX(id) AS LastId FROM Table1"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Execute
End With

' Open the recordset.
Set rstRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rstRecordset.ActiveConnection = cnnConn
rstRecordset.Open cmdCommand
MsgBox("last id = " & rstRecordset.Fields(0).value & ""))

' Close the connections and clean up.
cnnConn.Close
Set cmdCommand = Nothing
Set rstRecordset = Nothing
Set cnnConn = Nothing
```

Comment: Error 1 Type 'DAO.Recordset' is not defined. Error 2 'CurrentDB' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. "i tried fixing the errors by adding 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library' but didn't fix the second error. "i'll add my refences maybe it'll help

Comment: seems like i need to learn adodb before i can fully utilize the function... i'll vote up for now :)